# Ruby 'savon_model' gem soap request - initial request is anonymous. Second authenticated request returns successful response but times out

Tags: ruby, soap, httpclient, savon

I am just starting out in the ruby on rails world and have managed to get the below model to make a request and return a response. It uses the 'savon_model' gem which has 'savon', 'httpi' and 'httpclient' gems as dependencies.

```
class Incident
include Savon::Model

  client do
 http.auth.basic "testuser", ""
 http.headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate"
 http.headers["SOAPAction"] = '"RetrieveKeysList"'
 end

    endpoint "http://localhost:13080/SM/7/ws"
 namespace "http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7" 
    actions "RetrieveIncidentKeysListRequest"

  def self.all
    response = client.request("RetrieveIncidentKeysListRequest") do
 soap.body = {'wsdl:model' => 
     {'wsdl:keys' =>"",
     'wsdl:instance' =>""}
    }
 end
 h = response.to_hash
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger.debug "********value of H is #{h}"
 return h[:retrieve_incident_keys_list_response][:keys]
  end

end
```

I have 2 issues:

1) The request makes an anonymous soap request first, fails authentication, then makes a second request, authenticates correctly and returns a response.The response returns within a second or so. Is there something wrong in my model code that is causing the initial anonymous request?

```
POST /SM/7/ws HTTP/1.1
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
soapaction: "RetrieveKeysList"
content-type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
date: Mon, 13 Dec 2010 12:54:11 GMT
content-length: 427
host: localhost:13080

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Body><RetrieveIncidentKeysListRequest><wsdl:model><wsdl:keys></wsdl:keys><wsdl:instance></wsdl:instance></wsdl:model></RetrieveIncidentKeysListRequest></env:Body></env:Envelope>

HTTP/1.1 401
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=E7FFF77B44531BE3E28B239F0A900A5A; Path=/SM
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="CASM"
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 40
Date: Mon, 13 Dec 2010 12:54:11 GMT

POST /SM/7/ws HTTP/1.1
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
soapaction: "RetrieveKeysList"
content-type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
cookie: JSESSIONID=E7FFF77B44531BE3E28B239F0A900A5A
authorization: Basic ZmFsY29uOg==
date: Mon, 13 Dec 2010 12:54:12 GMT
content-length: 427
host: localhost:13080

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Body><RetrieveIncidentKeysListRequest><wsdl:model><wsdl:keys></wsdl:keys><wsdl:instance></wsdl:instance></wsdl:model></RetrieveIncidentKeysListRequest></env:Body></env:Envelope>

HTTP/1.1 200
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=21EE41B79757FA9C0E31FAB886A2899D; Path=/SM
Keep-Alive: timeout=1200000, max=1000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 9014
Date: Mon, 13 Dec 2010 12:54:14 GMT

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><RetrieveIncidentKeysListResponse xmlns="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7" xmlns:cmn="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7/Common" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" message="Success" query="" returnCode="0" schemaRevisionDate="2010-08-26" schemaRevisionLevel="1" status="SUCCESS" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7 http://localhost:13080/SM/7/ws/Incident.xsd"><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10001</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10002</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10003</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10004</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10005</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10006</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10007</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10008</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10009</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10010</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10011</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10012</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10014</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10015</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10016</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10017</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10018</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10019</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10020</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10021</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10022</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10023</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10024</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10025</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10026</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10027</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10028</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10029</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10030</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10031</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10032</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10033</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10034</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10035</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10036</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10037</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10038</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10039</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10040</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10041</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10042</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10043</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10044</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10045</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10046</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10047</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10048</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10049</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10050</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10051</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10052</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10053</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10054</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10055</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10057</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10058</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10059</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10060</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10061</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10062</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10063</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10064</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10065</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10066</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10067</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10068</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10069</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10070</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10071</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10072</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10073</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10074</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10075</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10076</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10077</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10078</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10079</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10080</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10081</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10082</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10083</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10084</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10085</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10086</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10087</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10088</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10089</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10090</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10091</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10092</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10093</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10094</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10095</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10096</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10097</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10098</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10099</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10100</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10101</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10102</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10103</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10104</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10105</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10106</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10107</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10108</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10109</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10110</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10111</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10112</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10113</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10114</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10115</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10116</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10117</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10118</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10119</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10120</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10121</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10122</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10123</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10124</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10125</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10126</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10127</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10128</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10129</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10130</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10131</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10132</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10133</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10134</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10135</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10136</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10137</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10138</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10140</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10141</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10142</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10143</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10144</IncidentID></keys><keys><IncidentID type="String">IM10145</IncidentID></keys></RetrieveIncidentKeysListResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

2) Even though the request is parsed and response returned as in the above log (which is from request application not rails app), the request times out on the rails side and nothing is written to screen. Below is the development.log entries and last few lines of the stack trace:

development.log

```
Started GET "/incidents" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-12-13 12:59:33 +0000
  Processing by IncidentsController#index as HTML
Completed   in 63517ms

HTTPClient::ReceiveTimeoutError (execution expired):
  app/models/incident.rb:15:in `all'
  app/controllers/incidents_controller.rb:5:in `index'

Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.0ms)
Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout
```

Last few lines of Stack Trace

```
httpclient (2.1.5.2) lib/httpclient/session.rb:804:in `readpartial'
httpclient (2.1.5.2) lib/httpclient/session.rb:804:in `block in read_body_length'
httpclient (2.1.5.2) lib/httpclient/timeout.rb:128:in `timeout'
httpclient (2.1.5.2) lib/httpclient/session.rb:802:in `read_body_length'
httpclient (2.1.5.2) lib/httpclient/session.rb:591:in `get_body'
httpclient (2.1.5.2) lib/httpclient.rb:958:in `do_get_block'
httpclient (2.1.5.2) lib/httpclient.rb:765:in `block in do_request'
httpclient (2.1.5.2) lib/httpclient.rb:848:in `protect_keep_alive_disconnected'
httpclient (2.1.5.2) lib/httpclient.rb:764:in `do_request'
httpclient (2.1.5.2) lib/httpclient.rb:666:in `request'
httpclient (2.1.5.2) lib/httpclient.rb:596:in `post'
httpi (0.7.2) lib/httpi/adapter/httpclient.rb:34:in `block in post'
httpi (0.7.2) lib/httpi/adapter/httpclient.rb:66:in `do_request'
httpi (0.7.2) lib/httpi/adapter/httpclient.rb:33:in `post'
httpi (0.7.2) lib/httpi.rb:93:in `block in post'
httpi (0.7.2) lib/httpi.rb:147:in `with'
httpi (0.7.2) lib/httpi.rb:91:in `post'
```

Apologies for the long winded message, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Joel

Comment: you are using pretty old versions of httpi and httpclient. you should update and retry